# update a single column in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`my goes! i have a status column in the applications table which i set to pending as default.
when the user submits the application, the status is pending. now am stuck here
1. i would like to have two buttons i.e approve and reject buttons in the managers view.
2. i want to update the status to approved from its default(pending) when the manager clicks the approve button and the same is true for the reject button

```
here is my controller for applications`
```

````
  def index
     @applications = Application.all
   end

  def new
    @application = Application.new

  end

def create
  @application = Application.new(application_params)
  if @application.save
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:notice] = ' Your application is submitted pending approval'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end


#my update method
    def update
      @applications = Application.all
      @application = Application.find(params[:id])
      @application.update_attributes(:status => "Approved")
        render 'index'
        flash[:notice] = "Application has been approved"
      end
    # def update
    #   @applications = Application.all
    #   @application = Application.find(params[:id])
    #   @application.update_attributes(:status => "Approved")
    #   render 'index'
    #      flash[:notice] = "Application has been approved"
    #    else
    #      @application.update_attributes(:status => "Rejected")
    #         flash[:notice] = "Application has been rejected"
    # end
  private

    def application_params
      params.require(:application).permit(:name, :phone_number, :email, :gender, :date_of_birth, :course, :address, :status)
    end

end```
`my views`
  ```<td><%= link_to "Approve", application_path(application.id), method: :put, :class => 'mb-sm btn btn-green' %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Reject", application_path(application.id), method: :put, :class => 'mb-sm btn btn-danger' %></<td>

and my routes
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'manager/index'
   get 'about/index'

  resources :contacts
  resources :registers
  resources :forms
  resources :applications

  # put 'applications/update'

  root to: "landing#index"

  devise_for :managers, path: 'managers', controllers: {sessions: "managers/sessions"}
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
      devise_for :users, path: 'users',  controllers: {sessions: "users/sessions"}
    end```
any one kindly help me
````

Comment: Try to edit your question, it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutebi, there is more than one way to do this. An easy to understand solution is to implement one controller action for setting status to :accepted and one for setting the status to :rejected.

In your controller:

```
# app/controllers/applications_controller.rb
def accept
  @application = Application.find params[:id]
  @application.status = :accepted
  @application.save
  # add more code as needed,
  # then render something
end

def reject
  @application = Application.find params[:id]
  @application.status = :rejected
  @application.save
  # add more code as needed,
  # then render something
end
```

Then, create the corresponding routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
ressources :applications do
  member do 
    put 'accept'
    put 'reject'
  end
end
```

This creates the following named routes

```
accept_application_path(@application)
reject_application_path(@application)
```

that you can use to create the requested links in your views:

```
# app/views/applications/_application.html
link_to "Approve", approve_application_path(@application), method: :put
link_to "Reject", reject_application_path(@application), method: :put
```

I must say that I haven't tested my solution, but except for the occasional typo, it should work. If not, let me know. Specifically, you might need to remove the @ from @application, depending on what type of variable you have in your view. From your controller it looks like an instance variable, but in your views you use a local variable. Make sure that this doesn't lead to an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089588/andreas-gebhard man thanks it worked. you are too intelligent thank you for your knowledge.  its know doing well

Comment: mutebi, glad I could help. I'm new here like you. Would you mind accepting my answer to help my reputation? All the best and good luck!